# Geoserver secure layer assess issue via PHP proxy

Tags: geoserver, security, proxy

I have a PHP script that sends request to geoserver layers. My layers are like this:

- topp:layer_unsecured
- topp:layer_secured

layer_unsecured is unsecured layer and layer_secured is secured.

I have created a PHP script:

```
private function execute($url, $returnheader, $timeout, $useragent, $httpheaders, $postfields)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $returnheader);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip, deflate");

    $result = array(
        "OUT"=>curl_exec($ch),
        "INF"=>curl_getinfo($ch),
        "ERR"=>curl_errno($ch)
    );

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

this script returns data if I send request to my unsecured layer with post data:

```
$post_data = array(
    'bbox'=>'1,2,3,4',
    'Format'=>'image/png',
    'request'=>'GetMap',
    'layers'=>'topp:layer_unsecured',
    'width'=>'256',
    'height'=>'256',
    'srs'=>'EPSG:4321'
);
```

this works fine.

But when I post data to secured layer with username and password not working:

```
    $post_data = array(
        'bbox'=>'1,2,3,4',
        'Format'=>'image/png',
        'request'=>'GetMap',
        'layers'=>'topp:layer_secured',
        'width'=>'256',
        'height'=>'256',
        'srs'=>'EPSG:4321',
        'username'=>'myuser',
        'password'=>'mypass'
    );
```

this not working.

Error code:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://10.2.3.35:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd"><ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
      Could not find layer topp:layer_secured
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Typo "top:layer_secured" is probably only in this question because in the code it is "topp:layer_secured", right?

Comment: I edited names but same error.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience on GeoServer security. Can you access your secured layer with some other means?

Comment: Yes Geoserver admin panel includes Demos menu. There is s Demo Request selection in this menu page. I am selecting GetMap request from this page and send request success with username password.

Comment: Does the same demo request work if you POST it with wget or curl? I mean that does it look like PHP is doing something differently? Also, does the request with username/password work with non-secured layer? Trying to catch if the reason is that Geoserver does not trust on the credentials which leads to denial. Non-secured layer should work in this case because there is no need for trust.